# How to select which screen ImageGrab.grab() grabs in a multi-monitor setup?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Like the title says, I'm curious if there is a way to configure the ImageGrab.grab() module to grab, for instance, the right screen, instead of the left in a multi-monitor setup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't possible, due to the manner in which the PIL obtains the dimensions of the display device. When it obtains the Device Context, it *does* obtain one for all attached monitors:

```
screen = CreateDC("DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

(**display.c**, line 296, version 1.1.7)

However, to get the display dimensions, it uses this code:

```
width = GetDeviceCaps(screen, HORZRES);
height = GetDeviceCaps(screen, VERTRES);
```

(**display.c**, lines 299-300, version 1.1.7)

Which only returns the dimensions of the primary, active monitor. All subsequent operations are done with these width and height values, resulting in a final image that is only the size of the primary display.

---

In order to receive a screengrab of all attached monitors, those two lines would need to be replaced with something like:

```
width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
```

After which you'd need to recompile PIL. This would provide you with the dimensions of the virtual screen, which is "... the bounding rectangle of all display monitors." [[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)]

A more correct implementation would be using [EnumDisplayMonitors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to obtain device contexts for the individual monitors, along with altering ImageGrab.grab()'s interface (or adding a new function) to allow for the selection of a specific monitor, of whose device context would be used for the remaining operations.

Comment: In your second implementation, I was able to find the handles for the monitors via enumDisplayMonitors.. but for the next step, would I need C, or can it be done in the ImageGrab module? If I'm following you correctly, the function I have to create would need to modify the CreateDC("DISPLAY", NULL, NULL) call, substituting 'DISPLAY' for the Device Handle I want to take snapshots of?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear, both of the options require modifying the C source code for PIL and recompiling it. You're correct, the CreateDC function is what needs to be altered.