# Why does PIL.ImageGrab.grab() not always return same sized image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using a remote ubuntu machine and I have code that looks roughly like this:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab

x = ImageGrab.grab()

# ... other arbitrary code ...

y = ImageGrab.grab()
assert(y.size==x.size) # fails
```

How is this possible?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error on windows 10 + dx11. Here is a clue of how ImageGrab take the size of your screen : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185797/how-to-select-which-screen-imagegrab-grab-grabs-in-a-multi-monitor-setup
Maybe it can help.

Comment: Does it still fail, when you remove all the "other arbitrary code" in between? If not, I guess, you'd need to show that part, too.

Comment: Actually I found out the answer was something really weird. I was using a remote gcloud session and apparently gcloud VNC session automatically resizes the screen to match your own but sometimes that lapses and so the screen size was just changing all over the place.